# Adding TAG to EMR Cluster

Tags: emr, amazon-emr

I am launching emr cluster using Java API but not able to associate a **tag** to it. Pl can you help me on this.

Using EMR CLI, it is very easy as below but I have to do this using my Java code

./elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --**tag tagKey=stackOverflow**

If you need more details on this, pl let me know..

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In earlier versions of EMR Java SDK there wasn't a way to add tags(not a direct one for sure) to add tags, but in newer versions of the Java SDK for EMR, there is a method named `addTags(Collection<Tag> tags)`, using which you can add tags to the resources(EC2) being launched as part of the EMR cluster.
You would use it as follows:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

AmazonElasticMapReduce emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();

Tag stackOverflowTag = new Tag();
stackOverflowTag.setKey("stackOverflow");

tags.add(stackOverflowTag);
AddTagsRequest addTagsRequest = new AddTagsRequest();
addTagsRequest.setTags(tags);

emr.addTags(addTagsRequest);
StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();
// set up the cluster to launch and add steps
RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
```

Use `com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.Tag` class in order to create tags, as there are many `Tag` classes present in the SDK, and for a moment I had imported the wrong one as well.

Read the doc [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.html#addTags%28%29).